# What's the proper way to install a go package to the system path?

Tags: go, raspbian

I'm trying to install a `go` project ([the keybase client, in particular](https://github.com/keybase/client/blob/master/go/README.md#building)), but I want to install it globally for all the users on my system.

I've searched around and found a few people who accidentally install things to `/usr/local/go/bin` or something to that effect, but no instructions on how I actually *should* be installing things to such locations.

But that's what I want to do - globally install the application. How should I be doing that with go?

<sub><sup>I'm not using any of the pre-built packages because none exist for Raspbian Jesse</sup></sub>.

Comment: You install it like anything else for your system, there's nothing special about it being written in Go. That page has prebuilt packages for mac and Linux.

Comment: amd32 and 64 linux, not ARM

Comment: Ah, didn't see the tiny print about Raspbian. Just copy the binary to a system PATH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach that I've taken is this:

```
PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin" GOPATH=/usr/local/go/ go get github.com/keybase/client/go/keybase
PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin" GOPATH=/usr/local/go/ go install -tags production github.com/keybase/client/go/keybase
```

Which ends out installing `keybase` to `/usr/local/go/bin/keybase`. It's possible that there's a better way, but so far I haven't seen one.

Comment: I would recommend against setting `GOPATH=/usr/local/go`, since that's the default GOROOT, and you never want to accidentally clobber something in GOROOT. (You did ask for the "proper" way, and that is still to install the resulting binary to a system path _after_ you build, like any other binary.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting $GOBIN like:

GOBIN=/usr/local/bin/ or GOBIN=/usr/bin/ or any directory in the PATH?

and then:

export GOBIN

and then install the app?

According to the manual the default $GOBIN is $GOROOT/bin so I guess those users set GOROOT to /usr/local/go

Comment: If you set your GOBIN to a directory where you don't have write permission, you are going to have problems with root owned files in your GOPATH after using `sudo` to build and install.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question. I tried in a VM and got a single keybase executable in my $GOBIN which I can run as any user.

Comment: The default system bin directories are only writable by root. If you ran `sudo go install`, you now have root owned files in your GOAPTH. You shouldn't be building software as root.

Comment: That *appears* to be exactly what I want, though. I mean, I don't *really* care who's doing the building, but I do want the executables to be... well, for me it appears that `/usr/local/go/bin` works fine.

Comment: I run build as user and then install as root. No root files after in GOPATH.

Comment: @WayneWerner Sorry can't comment on your answer, Update the PATH for all users permanently, for example in /etc/profile.

Comment: @Roeften That's exactly what I've done. Any user that wants to set their own GOPATH is more than welcome. I might be able to run the build command as nobody.

Comment: @Roeften: `go build` doesn't save the binary artifacts in GOPATH, `go install` does. `sudo go install` will leave those root owned artifacts in your GOPATH (unless they were previously installed by your regular user, and don't need to be updated), possibly causing later builds to fail.

Comment: @JimB Used go once in my life so no experience. I simply ran find $GOPATH -group root and got no hits. Tbh i was after the points in order to be able to comment in SO ;-)